# is there any way to totally disable certificate in k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, certificate

as we all know k8s cluster uses certs to authenticate communication between components, like etcd, apiServer, nodes etc.

```
CERTIFICATE                EXPIRES                  RESIDUAL TIME   CERTIFICATE AUTHORITY   EXTERNALLY MANAGED
admin.conf                 Dec 16, 2022 06:12 UTC   43d                                     no      
apiserver                  Dec 16, 2022 06:13 UTC   43d             ca                      no      
apiserver-etcd-client      Dec 16, 2022 06:14 UTC   43d             etcd-ca                 no      
apiserver-kubelet-client   Dec 16, 2022 06:14 UTC   43d             ca                      no      
controller-manager.conf    Dec 16, 2022 06:14 UTC   43d                                     no      
etcd-healthcheck-client    Dec 16, 2022 06:15 UTC   43d             etcd-ca                 no      
etcd-peer                  Dec 16, 2022 06:16 UTC   43d             etcd-ca                 no      
etcd-server                Dec 16, 2022 06:15 UTC   43d             etcd-ca                 no      
front-proxy-client         Dec 16, 2022 06:16 UTC   43d             front-proxy-ca          no      
scheduler.conf             Dec 16, 2022 06:17 UTC   43d                                     no
```

however people need to renew and maintain those licenses on regular basis(1 year normally).
in a testing environment, like QA, we don't really care too much of security, and with tens of QA k8s clusters, it takes significant amount of effort just to maintain those certs.
so just wondering if there is a way to tell k8s this is a test env, and disable all security manners so we don't have to maintain those certs.